# textarea to database including <p>

Tags: php

I receive a large chunk of text in a text area. Usually it's divided into a few paragraphs. How can I wrap these paragraphs in `<p>` tags so the text will be formatted the same when I read it out of the database again?

Comment: Have you considered using TinyMCE? That will format everything for you and store the markup in your database.

Comment: Do you already have the <p>-tags in your database or do you want to replace linebreaks with p-tags?

Comment: You can try wrapping output with <p> and </p> first, then replace (line break) "\n" with "</p><p>".

Comment: maybe `$text = '<p>' . implode("</p><p>", explode("\n", $textarea)). '</p>';`

Answer (score 0):

I would not add the tags to the database as you would have to strip them out again if you want to put the text in a text area again (or a text mail or whatever...), I would add the tags when you output to html only.

You can use explode by new-lines or multiple new-lines and add your tag to every non-empty element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

What about output?

```
<p><?=$content;?></p>
```

Comment: Well there will have to be more than one paragraph.